# Predicted values scatter plot angle

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling

Could you please come up with any possible explanation on why this happens when one uses a deep learning model to predict something? The points should be on a 45 degree angle but they seem to be on a 30 degree angle. (btw the same happens with a random forest model)

Any help would be appreciated and it will help my research and learning.[image]

Comment: Can you share your code for more context?